# Algorithm for expressing given number as a sum of two squares

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

My problem is as follows:

I'm given a natural number n and I want to find all natural numbers x and y such that

n = x² + y²

Since this is addition order does not matter so I count (x,y) and (y,x) as one solution.

My initial algorithm is to assume that y>x, for all x compute y²=n-x² and check if y is a natural number using binary search on y².

```
for(x=1;2*x*x<n;x++)
{
     y_squared=n-x*x;
     if(isSquare(y_squared)==false)
           continue;

     //rest of the code
}
```

Is there any improvement for my algorithm? I already checked if n can have solutions using two squares theorem, but I want to know how many there are.

My algorithm is O(sqrt(n) * log(n) )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce this to `O(sqrt(n))` this way:

```
all_solutions(n):
    x = 0
    y = floor(sqrt(n))

    while x <= y
        if x * x + y * y < n
            x++
        else if x * x + y * y > n
            y--
        else
            // found a match
            print(x, y)
            x++
            y--
```

This algorithm will find and print all possible solutions and will always terminate for `x <= sqrt(n / 2)` and `y >= sqrt(n / 2)`, leading to at most `sqrt(n / 2) + (sqrt(n) - sqrt(n / 2)) = sqrt(n)` iterations being performed.

Comment: x and y start sqrt(n) apart and the distance shrinks by at least 1 in each iteration, so it's also at most sqrt(n) iterations.

Comment: @KellyBundy well, not quite. The upper bound is actually `sqrt(2) sqrt(n)`, if you're going for exact values. Or do you mean `O(sqrt(n))`?

Comment: Where do you get that extra sqrt(2) from?

Comment: @KellyBundy we need to in-/decrement `x` and `y` `sqrt(n / 2)` times each, so a total of `2 * sqrt(n / 2) = 2 * sqrt(n) / sqrt(2) = sqrt(2) * sqrt(n)` operations.

Comment: More explicitly, you start with `distance = y - x = floor(sqrt(n)) - 0 = floor(sqrt(n))`. Then you loop like `while distance >= 0:`, and you decrease `distance` in every iteration by 1 or 2. Thus at most `floor(sqrt(n))` iterations.

Comment: @KellyBundy just noticed the mistake, thanks. I'm still wondering where the mistake in my logic is hidden. Your argumentation is obviously right.

Comment: I guess your mind is somehow locked at the "meeting point" sqrt(n/2), which I ignore :-). But with that meeting point, x can go at most sqrt(n/2) steps, which you got right. But y can go at most sqrt(n)-sqrt(n/2) steps, which is smaller than sqrt(n/2) (not sure what exactly it is, hence I find my reasoning simpler :-).

Comment: Ha. I tried evaluating sqrt(n)-sqrt(n/2) but that went nowhere. Then realized that we want to add the steps for x and the steps for y anyway: sqrt(n) + (sqrt(n)-sqrt(n/2)) = sqrt(n).

Comment: @KellyBundy oh, right. That's what I overlooked :D. `y` takes `sqrt(n) - sqrt(n / 2)` steps. I'm feeling pretty dumb right now

Comment: Well you came up with a nice solution. I posted a variation of it now. I'm considering changing it to `sum += x++ + x` etc, but I'm not sure that's very clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65279752/12671057), keeping track of the sum of squares and adjusting it just with additions/subtractions:

**Pseudo-code:** (evaluate `x++ + x` and `y-- + y` left-to-right, or do it like in the Python code below)

```
x = 0
y = floor(sqrt(n))
sum = y * y

while x <= y
    if sum < n
        sum += x++ + x
    else if sum > n
        sum -= y-- + y
    else
        print(x, y)
        sum += 2 * (++x - y--)
```

**Java:**

```
  static void allSolutions(int n) {
    int x = 0, y = (int) Math.sqrt(n), sum = y * y;
    while (x <= y) {
      if (sum < n) {
        sum += x++ + x;
      } else if (sum > n) {
        sum -= y-- + y;
      } else {
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        sum += 2 * (++x - y--);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Python:**

```
from math import isqrt

def all_solutions(n):
    x = 0
    y = isqrt(n)
    sum = y ** 2

    while x <= y:
        if sum < n:
            x += 1
            sum += 2 * x - 1
        elif sum > n:
            sum -= 2 * y - 1
            y -= 1
        else:
            # found a match
            print(x, y)
            x += 1
            sum += 2 * (x - y)
            y -= 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> all_solutions(5525)
7 74
14 73
22 71
25 70
41 62
50 55
```

Comment: Neat idea to keep track of the value formed by `x * x + y * y`. I'd keep the increment/decrement step away from the rest of the arithmetic though, especially since you're using `x++ + x == 2 * x + 1`. That stuff can get pretty messy with regards to evaluation-order.

Comment: @Paul Yeah, that's why I used Java, where I think left-to-right is guaranteed. And then I turned it into the pseudo-code, where it isn't. Hope people will just do the "normal" thing and read it left-to-right, or think a little themselves :-)